# windows command run standalone but not from python. something to do with device communication

Tags: android, python, adb, device, host

here is the scenario. my host is connected to two devices each having it own device ID. i wrote a script which basically sets the environment for whatever device i am working on. for example if i want reboot only device 1 and not device 2 i run the following in the windows command prompt
set ANDROID_SERIAL=
adb root
adb reboot
this causes only the deviceID1 to reboot and not deviceID2. but when i implement the same function in the script. it complains that more than once device found

here is the script that i wrote:

```
import sys
import os
import subprocess

def adb_root():

    return 'adb root'

def adb_remount():
    return 'adb remount'

def adb_reboot():
    return 'adb reboot'

def setSource(id):
    return 'set ANDROID_SERIAL=cd1d87bd'


def runCommand(cmd):
    try:
        return subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True)
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
        print('error running ', cmd)
        return ''
def AI(cmd):
    try:
        return subprocess.run(cmd, shell=True)
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
        print('error running ', cmd)
        return ''
def main():
    ID=sys.argv[1]
    print(ID)
    AI(setSource(ID))

    runCommand(adb_root())

    runCommand(adb_remount())
```

Comment: You will need to use the `-s` flag to redirect the commands to a particular device. https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html#directingcommands

Comment: thanks man it worked